# How to download a large public Google Drive folder with CLI without authentication?

Tags: debian, command-line, curl, wget, google-drive

I checked many existing answers and I still didn't find a tool that would work with public folder / no authentication.

I have a Google Drive URL that looks like this: `drive.google.com/drive/folders/alphanumbericalstring1-string2`

I am looking for a tool that will accept this folder as parameter and download all files present in the folder. The folder is not mine and I can't change any settings of it.

Comment: https://github.com/tanaikech/goodls ?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I tried and followed instructions, but I got the following error when trying to download the folder (it is a big folder): "Error 403: The attempted action requires shared drive membership., teamDriveMembershipRequired" The folder I am accessing is not mine, but it is public.

Comment: In general Dropbox is better for this, just leaving as a note to those who find this question who do have control over the folder.

Comment: Found a comment in some goodls issue https://github.com/tanaikech/goodls/issues/16#issuecomment-736342196 that led me to: https://github.com/Akianonymus/gdrive-downloader which seems to be working now. Thanks!

Comment: A little update: The first 50GB downloaded fine, then I had to configure OAuth API, guide for which is here: https://github.com/Akianonymus/gdrive-downloader/blob/master/auth.md#generating-oauth-credentials I guess 50GB is as good as it gets for "no authentication".

Comment: @miran80 If you've found an answer to your problem, feel free to self-answer below!